# How to get out of nested for? In Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a nested loop to display content and apply terms in my template.

```
 {% for class in class %}

{% if saveclass %}
 {% for saveclass in saveclass %}

            {% if class.colecl in saveclass.saveclass_tag %}
            save class exists!
            {{ class.levelclass_name }}<br>
            {% else %}
            save class not exists!
            {{ class.levelclass_name }}<br>
            {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}


{% else %}
    there is nothing save class
    {{ class.levelclass_name }}<br>
{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The first loop gives me the list of classes.
Then it is checked whether the saveclass variable exists or not, if there is, the second loop is executed.
In the second loop it gives me saveclass and I check if the class tag is in the saveclass table and I display the output.
The problem is that the inner circle has to end to get to the next class. And for this reason, both the first if and its else are executed.
Python and other languages use breaks for this, but Django does not have a break template.
What is your solution?
Thank

Comment: This is deliberately made difficult by Django, since this logic should ideally be in the view itself. The view should pass data to the template in such a manner that the template can easily render it.

Comment: I have to do some filtering in the template so that I can only display certain classes. What is the solution?

Comment: Just do what @AbdulAzizBarkat said, do the filtering in the view and keep the template simple. (also... please format your code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched and according to friends Django template did not allow the break of the ring and should be managed in views.